# Changing an image on hover but only if hovered for a set period of time (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change an image, but ony if hovered for a set period of time. I've tried using delay(), which kinda works, but the problem is that the hover animation is still triggered, after the mouse has been moved off the element.

Here's my code

```
$('.pack-list li').hover(function() {

  $(this).find('.pack-icon img').delay(1000).animate({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  }, 100, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $(this).attr('src','images/download-icon.png');

    $(this).animate({
      width: 30 + "px",
      height: 36 + "px"
    }, 100, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });


}, function() {
  $(this).find('.pack-icon img').attr('src','images/pack-icon.png');    
});
```

Comment: Even though it is possible achieving that using jQuery, I will primarily opt for a CSS3 option unless otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by using CSS3 [animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) without JavaScript.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.rise {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  
}

.container:hover .rise {
  animation: example 0.5s ease 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: example 0.5s ease 1s forwards;
  -o-animation: example 0.5s ease 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: example 0.5s ease 1s forwards;
}
.container:hover .rise:nth-child(2) {
  animation: example 0.5s ease 2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: example 0.5s ease 2s forwards;
  -o-animation: example 0.5s ease 2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: example 0.5s ease 2s forwards;
}
.container:hover .rise:nth-child(3) {
  animation: example 0.5s ease 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: example 0.5s ease 3s forwards;
  -o-animation: example 0.5s ease 3s forwards;
  -moz-animation: example 0.5s ease 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
     height: 100px;
     width: 0;
  }
  100% {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rise"></div>
  <div class="rise"></div>
  <div class="rise"></div>
</div>
```

The red squares will be shown in sequence while the coursor is covering the green block within 1, 2 and 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Had to make two animations and set the delay accordingly to animate one image after the other. You can see the result here http://xweasel.chris-cole.de/v3/search.php?Description=1080p

Answer (score 0):

1: Define a variable for a timer.
2: Define a time.
3: Clear timeout on leave.

```
var timer;
var delai = 500; // milliseconds

$('.pack-list li').hover(in, out);

function in(){    // Set timeout on enter

  timer = setTimout(function(){
    $(this).find('.pack-icon img').delay(1000).animate({
        width: 0,
        height: 0
      }, 100,

      // animate callback
      function() {
        // Animation complete.
        $(this).attr('src','images/download-icon.png');

        $(this).animate({
          width: 30 + "px",
          height: 36 + "px"
        }, 100, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      });
  },delai);
}

function out() {    // Clear timout on leave
  $(this).find('.pack-icon img').attr('src','images/pack-icon.png');
  clearTimeout(timer); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it!